# Save one form data in two different channel

Tags: channel-form

I have a form in one page which need to save in two different channel how it can be possible?
using channel form

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can submit to multiple channels at the same time with Channel Form at this time. One option would be to use something like [External Entries](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/external-entries) to create a sql database update. You could then submit your form via ajax to the template with your sql insert/update. (Also see [docs](http://engaging.net/docs/external-entries) for External Entries, subheading "As an Ajax Form", for an example)